# session data won't show

Tags: php, html, session

I don't know the problem.
The data is saved in the session but it only shows the last input.

```
        $_SESSION['data'][] = $_POST;
        $_SESSION['data']['lengtezijde'] = $_POST['lengtezijde'];
        $_SESSION['data']['kleur'] = $_POST['kleur'];
        $_SESSION['data']['hoogte'] = $_POST['hoogte'];

        ?><tr><?
        ?><th><?echo $_SESSION['data']['lengtezijde'];?></th><?
        ?><th><?echo $_SESSION['data']['kleur'];?></th><?
        ?><th><?echo $_SESSION['data']['hoogte'];?></th><?
        ?></tr><?
```

Comment: check your post values

Comment: First line is not useful if you make it one by one just after

Comment: Also i will point out how insecure it is to send raw user data to your sessions which am guessing you will used to process an sql query later.

Comment: @JulesR if i dont have that line it wont store anything

Comment: @BobbyAxe yea i know but it is for myself to calculate things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code also and it work me. Since it is an array, you must loop trough it to display the values and that is why I think it is giving you only the last value.

```
//Declare your variables
$lengtezijde = $_POST['lengtezijde'];
$kleur = $_POST['kleur'];
$hoogte = $_POST['hoogte'];

//Store it in session
$_SESSION['data'] = array(
    'lengtezijde' => $lengtezijde,
    'kleur' => $kleur,
    'hoogte' => $hoogte,
);
```

Now you can loop through your data and display it. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you for your time you mean like:                                       foreach ($_SESSION['data'] as $key => $value) 
  {

  }

Answer (score 0):

if i understand what you looking for you must check your $_POST

> i test this code

```
    $_SESSION['data'][] = "Test";
    $_SESSION['data']['lengtezijde'] = 'test1';
    $_SESSION['data']['kleur'] = 'test2';
    $_SESSION['data']['hoogte'] = 'test3';

    echo $_SESSION['data']['hoogte'];
    br();
    echo $_SESSION['data']['kleur'];
    br();
    echo  $_SESSION['data']['lengtezijde'];
```

> result :

```
test2
test1
test3
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have mentioned session_start() in First Line of your code ,
session_start() too, before you assign values to $_SESSION

Rest of things seems ok in your code.
Never use below kind of assignment it will ruin your machine memory . If you run your script you will see that on each refresh of the page this size will be increasing. that is not advisable.

```
   $_SESSION['data'][] = $_POST;
```